# System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception

The full exception looks like this:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

My code looks like this:

```
Public Function GetHash(password As String) As String Implements IHashManager.GetHash
        Dim uRL As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host & ":" & HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port & "/md5_hash.asp?val=" & password

        ' Dim myWebClient As New Net.WebClient
        Using myWebClient As New Net.WebClient
            Return myWebClient.DownloadString(uRL)
        End Using
    End Function
```

It throws the exception on the return line.

The aim of the code is to return a hash for a password using the current URL. I didn't write this code and I'm unsure why it errors. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check what the value of `uRL` is when you call `myWebClient.DownloadString()`. The "Additional information" is quite clear; you are getting a 404 error that says that the resource identified in `uRL` is not found/does not exist at that location.

Comment: You should also not be using code that you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the purpose of this question was to get a better understanding of the code and to fix the issue. I try not to use code I don't understand